# Programmatically setting SearchView to be open

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView in my activity using this code:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private TextView mStatusView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        setupSearchView(searchItem);

        return true;
    }

    private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

        if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        } else {
            searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        }

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        mStatusView.setText("Query = " + newText);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        mStatusView.setText("Query = " + query + " : submitted");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        mStatusView.setText("Closed!");
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is when the Activity is started, I want the SearchView to start off opened. It starts off "closed" like this:

[image]

but I want it to be "open" like this:

[image]

Anyway I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at the top of the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

`setIconifiedByDefault(false)`

Edit:

In order to have it collapsible but expanded at the start then programatically expand it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` with

```
searchItem.expandActionView();
```

and you'll probably need

```
mSearchView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried this but this makes it open ALWAYS not just initially open. I still want it to be collapsable

Comment: @Harry I've edited the answer there to factor that in

Comment: I actually got it working with `mSearchView.setIconified(false);`